# Can't concatenate 2 parameters into an Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting crazy about an issue concerning parameters and variables synatx in my Azure Devops Pipeline.

**My issue**

This is my main pipeline:

```
variables:
  location: westeurope

stages:
  - stage: DEV
    jobs:
    - template: deployInfra.yml
      parameters:
        location: $(location)
        rgName: $(rgName)
        environnement: DEV
```

Calling this template:

```
 parameters:
  environnement: ''
  rgName: ''
  location: ''
  resourceGroupName: $(environnement)_$(rgName)

jobs:
  - job: 
    variables:
      resourceGroupName2: $(environnement)_$(rgName)
    steps:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'MeetupSC'
        azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
            New-AzResourceGroup -Name $(resourceGroupName2) -Location ${{parameters.environnement}} -Force
```

param **rgName** is dynamically provided when running pipeline. I test with value **MYRG**

**What I try to do**

1. build a ressource group name by concatenating environnement + rgName

**What I get**

I tried every combinations (I guess) with $(), ${{}} or $[], none of them give me the right result.

Above is the best I can do but what I get is not:

DEV_MYRG, but $(environnement)_MYRG

If I switch from $resourceGroupName2 to $resourceGroupName I get: $(resourceGroupName2). The param is not resolved.

If I hard code RG name, I have another issue with environnement:

> The term 'environnement' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program

Don't understand

**What I need**

- What is so special with *environnement* parameter?
- How I can get environnement?
- How I can get DEV_MYRG?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax for parameters is `${{ parameters.X }}` or `${{ parameters['X'] }}`. The macro syntax `$(X)` is for *variables*, **not** parameters.

Also, you are misspelling *environment*. Ensure your parameters and variables are spelled correctly to avoid simple mistakes caused by typos.

Also also, your inline script is **definitely** not going to work as-is, as you are passing in the `environment` value for the `location` parameter.